How to connect Azure Open AI PE endpoint from Azure synapse workspace notebook
I have created a notebook in azure synapse and trying to connect to Azure Open AI but the open AI endpoint is only available via private endpoint. How can I connect to Azure Open AI endpoint via PE.
I have created a PE from Azure Synapse to Azure Open AI.
Both Open AI service and synapse workspace are in same Vnet & subnet, but they are under different resource groups.
The public network connection is disabled for Azure Open AI , but open for synapse workspace.
What do I use as the openai.azure_endpoint.
I have tried to use the azure open ai end point as is from the service, while the public network access is enabled and it works fine.
But if I try to use \<PE dns.open ai dns.openai.azure.com\> while the PE is enabled, then I am getting connection error.
What is the solution?
Code snippet:
%pip install openai

import openai
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

openai.api_key = "xxxxxx"
openai.azure_endpoint = "https://xxxx.openai.azure.com/"
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_version = "2023-12-01-preview"

response = openai.chat.completions.create(

model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
messages=\[{"role": "user", "content": """whats 2+2 """}\]
)

print(response.choices\[0\].message.content)


is your Synapse workspace created with a managed virtual network?
